# Css intellisense for bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, visual-studio

I just downloaded twitter bootstrap for my project in Visual Studio 2012. When I started coding than I didn't get the intelligence for bootstrap css classes. I am working on MVC-4 with razor view. How to get the css intellisense work for bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use VS2012 so I can't speak to the standard there but it surprises me to think that things like classes would be picked up by the intellisense for CSS (do I need an IDE change up in here?). Are your [HTML classes](http://tantek.com/2012/353/b1/why-html-classes-css-class-selectors) usually picked up for use in CSS for selectors?

Unless you're using LESS or Sass and are trying to get it to work with the unique properties found in those?